# Curvature flows for PL closed curves in the plane?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

I'm curious to what extent people have studied "curvature flows" on PL closed curves in the plane.

There's a paper by Gage and Hamilton from 1986 that describes the long-term behaviour of smooth curves in the plane under the curvature flow.

- [MR0840401 (87m:53003)
  Gage, M.(1-RCT); Hamilton, R. S.(1-UCSD)
  The heat equation shrinking convex plane curves. 
  J. Differential Geom. 23 (1986), no. 1, 69–96. 
  53A04 (35K05 52A40 58E99 58G11)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214439902)

A discrete version of this flow could go like this.  The ambient space for this will be the space of PL 1-dimensional compact connected submanifolds of $\mathbb R^2$ and for the sake of argument, let's fix the length of the intervals.  So the curve consists of $n$ straight line segments, and the $i$-th interval has length $l_i$, and the set $\{l_1,l_2,\cdots,l_n\} \subset (0,\infty)$ is the data that describes this space of closed curves.  The "curvature flow" would be the dynamical system given by placing a spring at each vertex of your curve (the spring acts on the angle), and you make the spring's "natural angle" to be $\pi$.   Is this flow complete like the Gage-Hamilton flow?

More generally, has there been much study of finitary analogues to the Gage-Hamilton flow, in the spirit of my initial question?  I imagine there has, I'm not sure which terms to search for on MathSciNet.

Answer (score 11):

This is not a complete answer, but in my book with Satyan Devadoss, *[Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/DCG/)*, we include (following Gage-Hamilton) a discussion of the delightful paper by
Bennett Chow and David Glickenstein,

> "Semidiscrete Geometric Flows of Polygons."
>   *American Mathematical Monthly*. April 2007.
>   ([link](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly/american-mathematical-monthly-april-2007))

Here is an image I made to illustrate their "discrete flow":

[image: DiscreteFlow]

They prove that every simple polygon evolves under their discrete flow so that it converges
to a point whose shape is asymptotically an affine transformation of a
regular polygon.

---

It is now clear that Ryan is seeking linkage reconfigurations. The key paper is
this:

> Robert Connelly, Erik D. Demaine, and Günter Rote, “Straightening Polygonal Arcs and Convexifying Polygonal Cycles”, *Discrete & Computational Geometry*, volume 30, number 2, September 2003, pages 205–239. ([author link](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/Linkage/))
>   
> [image: Fig1 CDR]

There have been quite a few papers following this one in the last decade.
I wrote a short news-article-like summary of this great result [here (arXiv link)](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.CG/0007042).

Comment: Thanks.  Have you seen an analysis of any flows that keep the edge lengths constant?

Comment: Ah, interesting question! There is work on morphings of arbitrary polygons to convex polygons, while all edges remain fixed in length, so it is a reconfiguration of a closed linkage. Perhaps this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I'm looking for a "linkage" version of the papers you cite.

Comment: @RyanBudney: I added a linkage reference. Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately the Connelly, Demaine and Rote paper takes as input to the motion more information than just the polygon -- they make a choice of "struts".  So their motion does not make sense as a continuous function on the space of all polygons, and in that regard it's not analogous to the Gage-Hamilton result.  Do you know if anyone has done work that does not involve making choices -- something that defines dynamics on the space of all polygons (as a space)?  Connelly-Demaine-Rote basically just show that the polygon space is connected.  I want a flow that gives contractibility.

Comment: I confess I do not understand the difference, as CDR operates on any collection of closed and open polygons simultaneously, and follows a differential equation, not unlike Gage-Hamilton. But we are speaking different languages and perhaps I cannot help further.

Comment: If you look at their proof they choose "struts" and there's more than one choice, generally.  So say you were to write a computer algorithm to perform the motion described in the CDR paper, you would have to choose the struts (as the DE isn't defined without a choice of struts, the the DE depends on the choice).  So if you vary the initial conditions (perturb the initial polygon a little) the motion your computer program performs would not always vary continuously with the input polygon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of (by now not so) recent work on the [Carpenter's Rule Problem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Carpenter%27s_rule_problem), which is the natural PL version of curve shortening (and indeed, Streinu's algorithm (as well as CDR) use some of the same ideas.